# android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally process exception flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, apk, build.gradle

I developed one flutter application. Now i want to generate the apk to publish in google play store. I followed the steps https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android. But getting error

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\\deerewrc\wewestmyrweweestos\myrewerewd-app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\\deerewrc\wewestmyrweweestos\myrewerewd-\android\app\build.gradle' line: 60

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

1.run flutter doctor 
2.run flutter doctor --android-licenses and accept all the licenses too. Still getting this error